# random added byte when downloading php file

Tags: php, laravel, file, binary, byte

I am trying to download a binary file from the server that uses PHP.
Somehow it randomly adds one byte at the front of the file, when downloading it:

**Result download** (Hex editor image):

[image: Hex editor image]

**Expected result download** (Hex editor image):

[image]

Things i have tried:
1. Headers aproach try 1

```
$filename = 'spss-export.sav';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=survey_2_SPSS_syntax_file.sav");
header("Content-type: application/download; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");
readfile($filename); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
exit;
```

2. Header aproach try 2

```
$filename = 'spss-export.sav';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
readfile($filename); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
exit;
```

3. Laravel response download

```
$filename = 'spss-export.sav';
return response()->download($filename);
```

Header aproaches produce files that only have the random byte at the begining, but laravel aproach produces the random byte and one missing byte at the end of file. Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Comment: I would think that the difference between your and laravels way is that laravel also sends the `Content-Length`-header with the filesize, which is why one byte is missing in the end when there's an extra byte added to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself:
You have to add **ob_end_clean()** before the file output. The laravel framework was somehow adding an extra space for files.

Reference if this doesnt work:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163628/extra-space-at-beginning-of-downloaded-image/163644#163644